# Angular template renders before dynamic data

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm facing a really annoying problem - the page renders before I get the data. In $(document).ready() the names are logged correctly and there are no errors in console. However, the displayed html is empty and displays correct data after refreshing the page.

This is my component.ts file:

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';
import {DataService} from '../../services/data.service';
import {ActivatedRoute, Router} from '@angular/router';
import * as $ from 'jquery/dist/jquery.min.js';
import 'jquery-ui/jquery-ui.min.js';

declare let jQuery: any;

@Component({
  selector: 'user-header',
  templateUrl: '../../templates/plan/header.html',
})
export class HeaderComponent {

  data;
  selectedCompany;
  selectedPlace;

  constructor(private dataService: DataService,
              private router: Router,
              private route: ActivatedRoute) {
    this.data = this.route.parent.snapshot.data;
    this.selectedCompany = this.data.companies[0];
    if (!this.dataService.selectedPlace.getValue()) {
      this.dataService.selectedPlace = this.selectedCompany.foodHandlingPlaces[0];
    }
    this.selectedPlace = this.selectedCompany.foodHandlingPlaces.filter(
        x => x.id === this.dataService.selectedPlace.getValue().id
    )[0];
    if (!this.selectedPlace) {
      this.selectedPlace = this.selectedCompany.foodHandlingPlaces[0];
    }

    const self = this;
    $(document).ready(function () {
      console.log('selectedCompany', self.selectedCompany.name);
      console.log('selectedPlace', self.selectedPlace.name);
    });
  }
```

This is part of my template (html) file:

```
<li class="dropdown">
  <select [(ngModel)]="selectedCompany" (change)="selectCompany()" id="company-select">
    <option *ngFor="let company of data.companies" [ngValue]="company">
      {{ company?.name }}
    </option>
  </select>
</li>
<li class="dropdown">
  <select [(ngModel)]="selectedPlace" (change)="selectPlace()" id="place-select">
    <option *ngFor="let place of selectedCompany.foodHandlingPlaces" [ngValue]="place">
      {{ place?.name }}
    </option>
  </select>
</li>
```

How to make the html wait for the data and then render?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4):

**STOP**
**USING**
**JQUERY**
**WITH**
**ANGULAR**

I can't say it enough. JQuery is made for manipulating the DOM, and you should not do that in Angular.

If you want to wait for your data to be loaded, use conditions in your HTML template.

```html
<li class="dropdown" *ngIf="selectedCompany && data.companies">
  <select [(ngModel)]="selectedCompany" (change)="selectCompany()" id="company-select">
    <option *ngFor="let company of data?.companies" [ngValue]="company">
      {{ company?.name }}
    </option>
  </select>
</li>
<li class="dropdown" *ngIf="selectedPlace && selectedCompany?.foodHandlingPlaces">
  <select [(ngModel)]="selectedPlace" (change)="selectPlace()" id="place-select">
    <option *ngFor="let place of selectedCompany.foodHandlingPlaces" [ngValue]="place">
      {{ place?.name }}
    </option>
  </select>
</li>
```

In your component

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { DataService } from '../../services/data.service';
import { ActivatedRoute, Router } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
  selector: 'user-header',
  templateUrl: '../../templates/plan/header.html',
})
export class HeaderComponent implements OnInit {

  data;
  selectedCompany;
  selectedPlace;

  constructor(
    private dataService: DataService,
    private router: Router,
    private route: ActivatedRoute
  ) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.data = this.route.parent.snapshot.data;
    this.selectedCompany = this.data.companies[0];
    if (!this.dataService.selectedPlace.getValue()) {
      this.dataService.selectedPlace = this.selectedCompany.foodHandlingPlaces[0];
    }
    this.selectedPlace = this.selectedCompany.foodHandlingPlaces.filter(
      x => x.id === this.dataService.selectedPlace.getValue().id
    )[0];
    if (!this.selectedPlace) {
      this.selectedPlace = this.selectedCompany.foodHandlingPlaces[0];
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Yes, I've been told that Angular and jQuery shouldn't go together, but I need it and removing it from the file entirely didn't help with the issue in hand.
Also - this solution unfortunately doesn't display the data.

Comment: `I need it` no you don't. Everything that JQuery does, Angular does the same. And what is your issue now ?

Comment: Guess I'm just used to jQuery. I will look into getting rid of it, though.
The issue remains - the data is not displayed. Now it also doesn't show the select boxes because of the *ngIf.

Comment: Well the, you don't get your data the right way. log every variable you try to assign and see if it has data.

Comment: I had issues with the filter function as well. The workaround that I found was to clone the array, something like : this.selectedPlace = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(array.filter())). For some reason the filter in some cases finishes after the next line is read.

Comment: @BoantaIonut make a [mcve] if you say things like that, because I've never faced this kind of issue.

Comment: Alright, lets say I have a class that contains a string and a boolean property. You are creating an array of elements of that custom class. After a while you have to submit only the elements which have the boolean property set on true. Assigning a constant only those elements like const ex = this.array.filter(element => element.booleanValue) amd then iterating over that constant was not working for me. The workaround that worked was const ex = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.array.filter(element => element.booleanValue))).

Comment: Sorry, but I cannot provide a live example right now, I just share my past experiences.

Comment: And as I just said, you can share all you want, but until you make a [mcve], don't say things like that, the only thing it does is inducing doubt in the head of people that already have an issue with their code.